# How to get all selected values from different inputs - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I see a lot of questions like that but mine is different from theirs. I have a form and the form includes 3 different select area for different variables. I want to get them but I don't know how to do and I'm newbie on Javascript and HTML.

*edit: I deleted the " sending database " part. It was part of the context.*

Here is HTML:

```
    <form>

  <p> Scores: </p>

    <select name ="scores:">
      <option value= " 9 " name= " 9 "> 9 </option>
      <option value= " 8 " name= " 8 "> 8 </option>
      <option value= " 7 " name= " 7 "> 7 </option>
      <option value= " 6 " name= " 6 "> 6 </option>
      <option value= " 5 " name= " 5 "> 5 </option>
      <option value= " 4 " name= " 4 "> 4 </option>
      <option value= " 3 " name= " 3 "> 3 </option>
      <option value= " 2 " name= " 2 "> 2 </option>
      <option value= " 1 " name= " 1 "> 1 </option>

    </select>

<p> Years: </p>


  <select id ="year">
  </select>

  <p> Languages: </p>

  <select name="language">
    <option value ="Aborginial", name = "Aborginial"> Aborginial </option>
    <option value="Arabic"> Arabic </option>
    <option value="Aramaic">Aramaic</option>
    <option value="Bosnian">Bosnian</option>
    <option value="Cantonese">Cantonese</option>
    <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
    <option value="Czech">Czech</option>
      </select>

  <button type="button">Submit data</button>
  </form>
```

Assuming user selected score 7, set the language to Bosnian and the year is 1980 ( I'm populating the year box with a function don't worry it is not empty list ) and I want to get these selected values (score: 7, lang: Bosnian, year:1980) By the way all of them are in the form. So how can I get these selected values?

Comment: How is your question different? The only difference I see with, for example,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript is that you have more than one `<select>`

Comment: I have 3 different selected area and different options are settled below them. So I can use the same function as they used? If it has the same solution, sorry for that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an object :

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData() {
var score = document.getElementById('scores').value;
var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
var language = document.getElementById('language').value;
var data = {'score':score, 'year':year, 'lang':language};
console.log(data);
}
```

```html
    <form>

  <p> Scores: </p>

    <select id ="scores" name ="scores:">
      <option value= " 9 " name= " 9 "> 9 </option>
      <option value= " 8 " name= " 8 "> 8 </option>
      <option value= " 7 " name= " 7 "> 7 </option>
      <option value= " 6 " name= " 6 "> 6 </option>
      <option value= " 5 " name= " 5 "> 5 </option>
      <option value= " 4 " name= " 4 "> 4 </option>
      <option value= " 3 " name= " 3 "> 3 </option>
      <option value= " 2 " name= " 2 "> 2 </option>
      <option value= " 1 " name= " 1 "> 1 </option>

    </select>

<p> Years: </p>


  <select id ="year">
  </select>

  <p> Languages: </p>

  <select id= "language" name="language">
    <option value ="Aborginial", name = "Aborginial"> Aborginial </option>
    <option value="Arabic"> Arabic </option>
    <option value="Aramaic">Aramaic</option>
    <option value="Bosnian">Bosnian</option>
    <option value="Cantonese">Cantonese</option>
    <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
    <option value="Czech">Czech</option>
      </select>

  <button id="submit" type="button">Submit data</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the following mistakes in your HTML:

1. No special symobols allowed in form elements name attribute.
2. You can't put comma after HTML attribute.
3. No need to put extra `<option>` tag attributes if your value equal to your option's name.

So in this code:

```
<select name="scores">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
```

You can access "scores" value as:

```
var select_scores = document.getElementById("form").scores;
select_scores.options[select_scores.selectedIndex].value;
```

Same for other form `<select>` elements.